# String data type of array key when iterated via for..in

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array. As far as I know array keys are integers in javascript.

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

When I get and log keys I get an array of integers.

```js
console.log([...array1.keys()]);

// Outputs=>  [0, 1, 2]
```

But in a for...in loop keys are string. But why and is there a way to type cast for integer keys?

```js
for (const key in array1) {
  console.log("Type of key "+key+" is "+ typeof key);
}

/* outputs:
Type of key 0 is string
Type of key 1 is string
Type of key 2 is string
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why and is there a way to type cast for integer keys?

Arrays are really just objects.
Array elements are just object properties whose *keys* are their respective indexes.
Property keys are always either string values or symbol values.

You can cast any string to a number using the `Number` function or the unary plus operator:

```
Number("5")
+"5"
```

However [you should probably avoid using `for...in` to iterate over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/218196).

Comment: "Avoid using for...in with arrays" is the answer for this question I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt()` function to cast string value to interger,

Ex:

```js
parseInt("1"); //return 1
```

Comment: Sure it can. Wonder if is there a more elegant way in new Ecma.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//actually the for in loop is used for objects , as the key in objects is always assigned as string whether you put a string or not

const obj = {a:1,b:2}
for (key in obj){
    console.log('typeof ',key,' is ',typeof key)
    console.log('valueof ',key,' is ',obj[key])
}
 
// Now because you used array the keys are indexes of the array so there for 0, 1, 2 .. and so on are logged as string not integers 
 
 //to solve this problem
 
const array = ['a','b','c']

//1. one can use the for each loop and used the index in the parameter

array.forEach((elem,index) => {
    console.log(elem,' ',index)
});

console.log(`2. use a for range loop`)

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i],i)
}

//3. using the same for key loop convert the key into index

for (const key in array) {
    console.log("Type of key "+Number(key)+" is "+ typeof Number(key));
  }
```